# Postgresql, jsonb_build_object and jsonb_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

Recently I have come across two queries as:

```
select jsonb_build_object('a', jsonb_agg(1))
 where false;

select jsonb_build_object('a', jsonb_agg(1))
 where false
having count(*) > 0;
```

First retuns `{"a": null}`, second - nothing, could you please explain me what happens in these 2 queries? I would expect nothing in result for BOTH.

Comment: Second query returns nothing because it filtered all records. If you have no records then result is nothing not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not related to JSON functions.

```
select count(1) where false;
```

and

```
select count(1) where false having count(1) > 0;
```

providing same effect.

First query reporting that there is 0 records satisfied given condition in the `where` clause and in the second query `having` clause filtering out rows from the first query where `count(1)` <= 0